# Subprocess polluting the parent terminal when using pty

Tags: python-3.x, linux, subprocess, pty

#### Example

I've noticed this behavior with the cli application [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It's only special for this example because it pollutes the parent process terminal. Its core functionality isn't important.

Getting the executable:

```
wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
unzip ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
# There is `ngrok` executable in this dir now
```

The code which creates the issue:

```
# ngrok_python.py
# It's in the same dir as the ngrok executable
import pty
import subprocess
import shlex
import time
import sys

pty_master, pty_slave = pty.openpty()
ngrok_cmd = "./ngrok http 80" 
# This doesn't happen for others
# ngrok_cmd = "ls -la" 

ngrok = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(ngrok_cmd), stdin=pty_slave, stdout=pty_slave, stderr=pty_slave)

# It also won't pollute the current terminal when redirected to DEVNULL
# ngrok = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(ngrok_cmd), stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

print("The subprocess is attached to the pseudo terminal")
print("Its output should not be printed here")
print("Unless I decide to read from pty_master")

print("Checking a few times if the subprocess is done")

for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(1)
    if ngrok.poll is not None:
        print("Subprocess finished")
        sys.exit()

print("Don't want to wait any longer.")
```

```
# Running the command
python3 ngrok_python.py
```

**Expected behavior**

- The only output will be from the print statements
- `subprocess` has custom `stdout/err/in`. It has not way to access the master terminal
- Because of the `pty` if I wanted to read what's going on in the subprocess I would read it from `pty_master`

**Actual behavior**

- The output of the subprocess `./ngrok http 80` consumes the terminal

The strange part is that running the commented out parts (`ngrok_cmd = "ls -la"` or `subprocess with subprocess.DEVNULL`) results in expected behavior.

#### Questions

1. Why does a child process know how to get access to the parents terminal if `stdout/err/in` the child was provided with have changed?
2. How to overcome this in python?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not willing to run an executable downloaded from some random site, but I'm willing to bet that `ngrok` explicitly opens and writes to `/dev/tty` in order to present its connection information.

The `/dev/tty` device refers to the process's "controlling terminal", which is one of the things that a process inherits from its parent.  Reassigning the child's `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` does not affect its controlling terminal.  So in this case the child retains the same controlling terminal as the parent, and when the child opens and writes to `/dev/tty` the output goes straight to the parent's screen, not passing through the child's `stdout` or `stderr` or your pseudo-terminal.

To achieve what you're looking for you need to divorce the child from the parent's controlling terminal and establish the slave end of the pseudo-terminal as the child's controlling terminal.  That involves calls to `setsid` and/or `setpgrp`, some file-descriptor juggling and possibly some other gyrations.  All of this is handled by `login_tty` if you're working in C.

The good news is that there's a method in the Python `pty` module that will do all of these things for you.  That method is [`pty.spawn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html?highlight=openpty#pty.spawn).  It's available in Python 2 and 3.  I've linked to the Python 3 documentation because it's much, much better and includes an example program.  `pty.spawn` basically behaves as a combination of `fork`, `exec`, `openpty` and `login_tty`.

If you rework your program to use `pty.spawn` to launch `ngrok` then I'm pretty sure you'll get the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. This assumption that `ngrok` is writing directly to `/dev/tty`, is that just a theory that would explain the behavior of `ngrok` or a more general design pattern which could address some problem? (am assuming just making it more difficult to detach from the masters terminal isn't a design motivation on its own)?

Comment: Opening `/dev/tty` isn't very common, but it's the go-to solution if your program needs to control the placement and/or visual attributes of text on a terminal screen and you can't, or don't want to, depend on one of the standard I/O streams being attached to the terminal.  `/dev/tty` can also be used when you want an out-of-band interaction with the user, especially if you want to control the visual nature of that interaction, which is why `getpass` (and `getpassphrase` on some platforms) uses it.